# Default document on IIS 10 is not working and returns 200

Tags: iis, iis-10, default-document

I setted Root config like it.
[Root Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbBqR.png)

And also, site include all of them and added `main.html`
[Site Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3iXU.png)

Full captures are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcQ2A.jpg)

But my site doesn't load any files and returns 200 code.
How can I fix it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis You need to dig FRT first.

Comment: FRT isn't work. I already tried.

Comment: what did you get from FRT? Reading its trace requires experience but it definitely should reveal enough information.

Comment: It doesn't log anything.

Comment: Some locations are return 404 Not Found. But most of them are return 200 OK.